# Set default refresh rate in AOSP 13

Tags: android, android-source

I want to set default refresh rate to 120Hz for display in my custom AOSP (Android 13).

I have changed config values in file, but it has not any affect

> frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml

```
<integer name="config_defaultRefreshRate">120</integer>
<integer name="config_defaultPeakRefreshRate">120</integer>
```

I there any other way?
I also want to enable the "Smooth Display" option by default in Settings->Display window.

Comment: Are you sure your graphics driver supports 120Hz?

Comment: @Robert Yes, when I enable smooth display from settings, I can see the refresh rate 120 via developer option.